# Second user cannot Publish to Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Sorry in advance - I've just been following tutorials and have spent ages on this trying to get this to work, but I have a fairly limited knowledge of the development side of Facebook!

I have created an App with the Open Graph settings set with the standard Read and Article as action/objects I will use for my website. I have tested a button "Post to Timeline" on an article page and it works, fantastically. However, when I forward it to my friend (who I have made a developer) and she clicks the button, she gets the following error:

"(#3501) User is already associated to a article object on a unique
action type Read. Original Action ID: (10150563976761680)"

How do I avoid this? Is the access token exclusively applicable to me? Or is it because it's still pending submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the settings for your Open Graph action.

- Go to the Open Graph Dashboard for your app on Facebook Developers.
- Click on the **Read** action.
- Click the **Advanced** link.
- Make sure that **Allow Multiple** is selected for the setting called **Unique action**.

(or simply **Read** another **Article**)

Comment: There is no **Advanced** link after clicking on the **Read** action. Is this because it's still pending submission?

Comment: It should be there, near the bottom of the page. [screenshot](http://jocke.syk.se/advanced.jpg)

Comment: I see a different page ([screenshot](http://www.entertainmentcocktail.com/screen/Facebook3.JPG))

Comment: OK. It seems you don't get as many settings for the builtin actions. Have you tried **reading** another **article**? Do you still get that error message?

Comment: You both get different screens because he is using an [in-built version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read) of the read action and you are using a [custom read action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/#configure).